# What's the best way to construct this LINQ query using orderby and group by?

Tags: linq, count, group-by, sql-order-by

I am learning LINQ and it took me over an how to figure out how to get my data the way I wanted it from mongoDB.  There seems like there should be a better way than this.

The basic premise is in the `UserMessage` collection there exists an ID I'm trying to groupby.  I want to order by the `DateCreated` in the `UserMessage`.

It would also be nice to return a COUNT for the groups as well, but I think I'm ready for some help. :)

```
//get from the db all the mssages to this user and from
var result = (from messages in session.All<UserMessage>()
              where messages.To == User.Identity.Name ||
                 messages.From == User.Identity.Name
              orderby messages.DateCreated descending
              select messages).ToList().GroupBy(t => t.AssociatedMessageID);
              //.Select(g => new { AssociatedMessageID = g.Key });

var result2 = from m in result.ToList()
              orderby m.First().DateCreated descending
              select m;

List<IGrouping<string,UserMessage>> aryMsg = result2.ToList();

foreach (IGrouping<string,UserMessage> um in aryMsg)
{
    //in this loop assign various members of each UserMessage to a view model
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It isn't necessary to have that many `ToList()` conversions (unless mongoDB doesn't support grouping).  It will do nothing but hurt performance.  The second ordering of the groups isn't necessary since all messages were sorted so the groups should be sorted as well.  Ultimately, I think your query is just this:

```
var aryMsg = (from um in session.All<UserMessage>()
              where um.To == User.Identity.Name
                 || um.From == User.Identity.Name
              orderby um.DateCreated descending)
             .AsEnumerable()
             .GroupBy(um => um.AssociatedMessageID)
             .ToList();
```

Comment: the monogoDB driver is throwing an exception with this - The method 'GroupBy' is not supported.